ModSecurity turn off rules by IP for given URI for Apache server behind load balancer
For a given URI when a post request is executed, the given IP will be whitelisted for given ctl rules, where the server is behind a loadbalancer.
Here's a rule that allows traffic to the server. The problem is that it allows traffic for any IP. Changing the ctl to REQUEST_HEADERS rule would not be valid.
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/api/hello-world.*" \
    "phase:1,id:2000,log,allow,ctl:ruleRemoveById=942230,ctl:ruleRemoveById=980130"
    SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:X-Forwarded-For "@contains 123.123.123.123" \
        "id:2001"

Here are different rules that I've tried without success
Example 1:
# Rule to identify allowed client IP and target URI
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:X-Forwarded-For "^123\.123\.123\.123$" "phase:1,id:20008,t:none,setvar:tx.allowed_ip=1"
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/api/hello-world.*" "phase:1,id:20009,t:none,setvar:tx.target_uri=1"

# Rule to apply ctl actions if allowed IP and target URI match
SecRule TX:allowed_ip "@eq 1" "phase:2,id:20010,ctl:ruleRemoveById=942230,ctl:ruleRemoveById=980130,chain"
    SecRule TX:target_uri "@eq 1" "t:none,id:20010"
    enter code here


Example 2: This one prevents the server to start
# Rule to identify allowed client IP
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:X-Forwarded-For "^123\.123\.123\.123$" "phase:1,id:20008,t:none,setvar:tx.allowed_ip=1,skipAfter:END_ALLOWED_IP"

# Rule to identify target URI
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/api/hello-world.*" "phase:2,id:20009,t:none,setvar:tx.target_uri=1,skipAfter:END_TARGET_URI"

# Rule to apply ctl actions if allowed IP and target URI match
SecRule TX:allowed_ip "@eq 1" "phase:2,id:20010,chain,skipAfter:END_CHAIN"
    SecRule TX:target_uri "@eq 1" "t:none,ctl:ruleRemoveById=942230,ctl:ruleRemoveById=980130"
    SecRule TX:target_uri "!@eq 1" "t:none, id:20011"

Example 3 doesn't let the server to start
ecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:X-Forwarded-For "^123\.123\.123\.123$$" "phase:1,id:20008,t:none,setvar:tx.allowed_ip=1"
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/api/hello-world.*" "phase:1,id:20009,t:none,setvar:tx.target_uri=1"

# Rule to apply ctl actions if allowed IP and target URI match
SecRule TX:allowed_ip "@eq 1" "phase:2,id:20010,ctl:ruleRemoveById=942230,ctl:ruleRemoveById=980130,chain"
    SecRule TX:target_uri "@eq 1" "t:none,id:20011"

I've tried many other combinations that don't seem to give me the desired output:
Allow the source ip to post requests bypassing certain ctl based on the URI.
I understand there are better ways of doing this, such as enabling the Loadbalancer IP and then making sure the Loadbalancer if configured correctly, to avoid IP spoofing etc, but it's out of scope.
The purpose of this exercise is to build a function that allows the source ip to post requests bypassing certain ctl based on the URI.
Thanks for taking the time

Try this:
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /api/hello-world" \
    "id:2000,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:X-Forwarded-For "@contains 123.123.123.123" \
        "ctl:ruleRemoveById=942230"

Never exclude rule 980130. If you are using CRS and want to completely disable firewall, use ctl:ruleRemoveByTag=OWASP_CRS.

403, not passing.

Can you show logs?

403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource.

I mean logs from modsecurity.
